# jquery each function to get the class value content

Tags: jquery, each

**script**

```
$("#activities").next().next().each(function(i) { });
```

**html**

```
<div class="head" id="activities" >Activities</div>
<div class="sub-head"> <span class="title">Activity</span> <span class="value">Min</span> <span class="unit">Calories</span> </div>
<div class="rows"> <span class="title">bicycling</span> <span class="value">30</span> <span class="unit">174</span> </div>
<div class="rows"> <span class="title">fishing and hunting</span> <span class="value">30</span> <span class="unit">261</span> </div>
<div class="rows"> <span class="title">transportation</span> <span class="value">30</span> <span class="unit">261</span> </div>
<div id="activitiesData"></div>
```

can anybody please help me to get datas from this div using each in jquery?

Comment: please show what specific data it is you want to extract

Comment: actually i want to extract the sum  of <span class="value">30</span> 30+30+30

Answer (score 4):

you can select `.rows` elements directly instead of traversing the DOM by using multiple `next()` methods, try the following:

```
var sum = 0;  
$(".rows .value").each(function(){
       var val = parseInt($(this).text(), 10)
       if (!isNaN(val)) {
            sum += val
       }          
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3nYWK/1/)

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
var sum = 0;
$('#activities').nextAll('.rows').find('.value').each(function() {
    var n = parseInt($(this).text(), 10); 
    if (!isNaN(n)) sum += n; 
});
```

Comment: .value is not a child of #activities

Comment: yes ankit .value is not a child of #activities so can we use .next() for that?

Comment: @AnkitGautam yes, that's what happens when the OP doesn't indent their HTML properly.  That's fixed now.

Comment: thanks every one for the support ,itz nicely working ,cheers guys

Comment: @Raminson yes, it will if the fields aren't valid numbers.

Comment: @Alnitak +1 it works now, sorry, as a side note, is this necessary to traverse the DOM first using an ID selector and then nextAll()?

Comment: @Raminson that depends on the markup - I just wasn't taking any chances.  Yours would work too, given the limited sample the OP provided.

Answer (score 2):

Please check here for the solution.

```
$('#GetTitles').click(function(){
    $('div.rows .title').each(function(){
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Sample Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/HDrSF/)

Comment: thanks every one for the support ,itz nicely working ,cheers guys

Answer (score 1):

To get each individual value in an array:

```
var values = $(".value", ".rows").map(function(i, e) {
    return parseInt(e.innerHTML, 10);
})​;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bGwrS/24/)

To get the combined sum of the values

```
var value = 0;
$.each($(".value", ".rows"), function(i,e) {
    value += parseInt(e.innerHTML, 10);
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bGwrS/25/)